# How To Add Custom Form Fields To The User Profile Page?

Tags: multisite, customization, users

The user profile page has the following fields:

Username
First Name
Last Name
Nickname 
Display name
Contact Info
E-mail
Website 
AIM 
Yahoo IM
Jabber / Google Talk

How can more fields be added to this section. Field such as Phone number, address, or anything else.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to use the `'show_user_profile'`, `'edit_user_profile'`, `'personal_options_update'` and `'edit_user_profile_update'` hooks.

Here's some **code to add a Phone number**:

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'yoursite_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'yoursite_extra_user_profile_fields' );
function yoursite_extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) {
?>
  <h3><?php _e("Extra profile information", "blank"); ?></h3>
  <table class="form-table">
    <tr>
      <th><label for="phone"><?php _e("Phone"); ?></label></th>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="regular-text" 
            value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'phone', $user->ID ) ); ?>" /><br />
        <span class="description"><?php _e("Please enter your phone."); ?></span>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<?php
}

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'yoursite_save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'yoursite_save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
function yoursite_save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
  $saved = false;
  if ( current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) {
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'phone', $_POST['phone'] );
    $saved = true;
  }
  return true;
}
```

That code will add a field to your user screen that looks something like this:

[image]

There are also several blog posts available on the subject that might be helpful:

- [**Adding and using custom user profile fields**](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields)
- [**Adding Extra Fields to the WordPress User Profile**](http://bavotasan.com/tutorials/adding-extra-fields-to-the-wordpress-user-profile/)

Or if you prefer not to roll-your-own there are plugins that add said features such as the following *(although I'm sure there are others):*

- [**Cimy User Extra Fields**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/)

Comment: Mike, I ran into a bunch of trouble get my modifications to save. I finally nailed it when I did a complete "find and replace". For my future reference, are the "name" and "title" fields required to be an exact match?

Comment: @Jonathan Wold - *"are the "name" and "title" fields required to be an exact match?"*  You didn't give me enough context for me to know how to aswer. And you may want to create [a complete new question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @MikeSchinkel Cimy User Extra Fields is imo no good recommendation. Support isn't really there and the code is ... hm.

Answer (score 8):

```
// remove aim, jabber, yim 
function hide_profile_fields( $contactmethods ) {
    unset($contactmethods['aim']);
    unset($contactmethods['jabber']);
    unset($contactmethods['yim']);
    return $contactmethods;
}

// add anything else
function my_new_contactmethods( $contactmethods ) {
    //add Birthday
    $contactmethods['birthday'] = 'Birthday';
    //add Address
    $contactmethods['address'] = 'Address';
    //add City
    $contactmethods['city'] = 'City';
    //add State
    $contactmethods['state'] = 'State';
    //add Postcode
    $contactmethods['postcode'] = 'Postcode';
    //add Phone
    $contactmethods['phone'] = 'Phone';
    //add Mobilphone
    $contactmethods['mphone'] = 'Mobilphone';

    return $contactmethods;
}
add_filter('user_contactmethods','my_new_contactmethods',10,1);
add_filter('user_contactmethods','hide_profile_fields',10,1);
```

Hope this helps.

Source: [WPBeginner](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-remove-default-author-profile-fields-in-wordpress/)