# Filter index page plugin

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I am looking for a wordpress plugin that allows my users to customize which posts are appearing on the home page. The users should have a settings page where they can select which categories and tags they´d like to see posts from.

Do you know if anything like that has been developed? Free or premium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am looking for a wordpress plugin that allows my users to customize which posts are appearing on the home page.

Not sure there's any particular plugins for this, but it's certainly possible with a few functions.

> The users should have a settings page where they can select which categories and tags they´d like to see posts from.

Easier than providing a settings page that's seperate from the profile page, i'd actually suggest adding a couple of new fields to the user's profile page, you can call the section **home preferences** or whatever you like.

Example follows...

## Step 1 - Add custom fields to the user profile page

Here i took the same approach as Mike did when answering:
[How to add custom form fields to the user profile page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4028/how-to-add-custom-form-fields-to-the-user-profile-page), firing on two actions to account for user profile saves and admin user edits.

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'home_prefs_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'home_prefs_profile_fields' );

function home_prefs_profile_fields( $user ) { 

    $um = get_user_option( 'taxonomy_selection', $user->ID );
    $tags = ( isset( $um['post_tag'] ) ) ? $um['post_tag'] : array();
    $cats = ( isset( $um['categories'] ) ) ? $um['categories'] : array();
    ?>
    <div id="home-prefs">
    <h3>Home Preferences</h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="tax_input[post_tag]">Tags</label><br />
                <span class="description">Choose which tags you want to display on the home page.</span>
            </th>
            <td>
                <ul id="tag-checklist">
                    <?php wp_terms_checklist( 0, array( 'taxonomy' => 'post_tag', 'selected_cats' => $tags ) ); ?>
                </ul>
                <br class="clear" />
                <hr />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="post_category">Categories</label><br />
                <span class="description">Choose which categories you want to display on the home page.</span>
            </th>
            <td>
                <ul id="category-checklist">
                    <?php wp_category_checklist( 0, 0, $cats, false ) ?>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <?php 
}
```

Information on the term and category checklists can be found in the source(no docs yet).
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.2/wp-admin/includes/template.php#L217

## Step 2 - Handle saving data on profile/user update

Again, two actions, depending on whether it's a user saving profile changes or another user making changes to another user's profile.

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_home_prefs' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_home_prefs' );

function save_home_prefs( $user_id ) {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return false;

    $data = array();

    if( isset( $_POST['tax_input'] ) ) {
        foreach( $_POST['tax_input'] as $taxonomy => $term_ids )
            if( !taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) )
                continue;
            else
                $data[$taxonomy] = array_map( 'intval', $term_ids );
    }

    if( isset( $_POST['post_category'] ) )
        $data['categories'] = $_POST['post_category'];

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'taxonomy_selection', $data );
}
```

**NOTE:** It wouldn't hurt to add further sanitization to the above.

## Step 3 - Adjust the CSS

Indent children terms, float the main list items, so busy taxonomies don't consume so much height.

```
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-user-edit.php', 'tax_checklist_css' );
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-profile.php', 'tax_checklist_css' );

function tax_checklist_css() {
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .children { text-indent: 20px }
        #tag-checklist li { float:left;width:30% }
        #category-checklist li { float:left;width:30% }
        #category-checklist li li { float:none;width:auto }
    </style>
    <?php
}
```

**NOTE:** 30% width on the list items basically gives you the appearance of 3 columns of terms, you're welcome to adjust the CSS to suit.

This could also just as easily be turned into an enqueue, which will provide some level of caching, inline CSS is quicker to test is all... ;)

## Step 4 - Filter home query based on user prefs

Add a filter onto home queries based on user configured settings for tags and categories.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'do_user_post_selection' );

function do_user_post_selection( $query ) {

    if( !is_home() || !is_user_logged_in() )
        return;

    if( isset( $query->query_vars['post_type'] ) && ( 'nav_menu_item' == $query->query_vars['post_type'] ) )
        return; 
    if( 1 < did_action('wp') )
        return;
    global $current_user;

    $tax_selection = get_user_option( 'taxonomy_selection', $current_user->ID );

    if( empty( $tax_selection ) )
        return;

    if( isset( $tax_selection['categories'] ) && ( is_array( $tax_selection['categories'] ) ) && ( !empty( $tax_selection['categories'] ) ) ) 
        $query->set( 'category__in', $tax_selection['categories'] );
    if( isset( $tax_selection['post_tag'] ) && ( is_array( $tax_selection['post_tag'] ) ) && ( !empty( $tax_selection['post_tag'] ) ) ) 
        $query->set( 'tag__in', $tax_selection['post_tag'] );

    return;
}
```

**NOTE:** You don't have to use a `pre_get_posts` filter, you could use `parse_query` or pass values into a `WP_Query` object, i personally just find the chosen hook easy to use(and it's what i'm use to using).

**UPDATE:** *Move the home prefs elements to the top of the profile page.*

```
function move_prefs() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('#home-prefs').prependTo('#your-profile');
            $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled',false);
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'admin_head-user-edit.php', 'move_prefs' );
add_action( 'admin_head-profile.php', 'move_prefs' );
```

**NOTE:** *There's a slight HTML update to the `home_prefs_profile_fields` function also required, i've updated the function as appropriate in **Step 1**.*

**RE: Checkboxes showing disabled from subscribers(see comments).**
*The reason this occurs is due to a capability check in the term checklist functions, these functions are typically used on post creation type screens, so expect the user to have the capability to assign terms to a post(or type), this obviously doesn't apply to this particular case so we can safely remove the disabled attribute from them(jQuery above has been ammended with the appropriate change).*

Hope that helps... :)

Comment: Thanks mate. I am getting a parse error. Can you spot it?

Comment: Can you narrow it down to a particular function? All works fine for me(i was testing the code as i went).

Comment: The parse error was caused on my part. Excellent code. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Is it possible to make the homepage settings appear first on the profile page?

Comment: There aren't any hooks specifically that will allow the elements to be placed that early, however you could use some jQuery to move them. I'll update my answer with an example for you.. ;)

Comment: What is needed to make the homepage settings available to "Subscribers" (registered users are set with subscriber priveliges). Now the check boxes are disabled.

Comment: Sorry that's due to a conditional check in the checklist functions, we can work around that(because it doesn't apply in this case) by removing the disabled attribute with some jQuery. Will update my answer again(and i'd welcome you marking my answer if it's addressed your original question)... :)

Comment: The do_user_post_selection function seems to be messing up the navigation menus on the site. I´m using wp_nav_menu to display a custom built menu. When logged in, it seems my custom menu is replaced by the default wp_nav_menu (it lists all pages on my site).

Comment: Updating the function now, just needs another conditional check on the post type.... :)

Comment: Happy to hear it's working for you... :)

Comment: Wow. Nice code, t31los! One thing you might change: instead of trying to anticipate all the times `pre_get_posts` could be used within `do_user_post_selection`, you might also check for this: `if( 1 < did_action('wp') ){ return; }` . That way the code only runs once, and never runs after the query is parsed.

Comment: Where/when does the `wp` action fire then? Not sure i follow what your suggested code does(curious to understand though).

Comment: Makes total sense now, have updated the code with that addition.. thanks.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This code is untested, but put it in your function.php file ans see what happends.

In theory this should happen:

- It adds an extra menu item in the admin interface
- Adds two meta boxes for categories and tags

In your template, all you have to do is get the values from the meta tags by using this:

```
$categories = get_option('fp_categories');
$tags = get_option('fp_tags');;
```

Then use this in you `query_post`.

This is the plugin / code:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'cms_options_menu');


function cms_options_menu() {

    //create new top-level menu
    add_menu_page('CMS options', __('CMS options'), 'administrator', __FILE__, 'cms_options_page',plugins_url('/images/icon.png', __FILE__));
    //call register settings function
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_cms_options' );
}


function register_cms_options() {
  //register our settings
  register_setting( 'cms-options', 'fp_categories' );
  register_setting( 'cms-options', 'fp_tags' );
}


function cms_options_page() {
?>
<div class="wrap">
<h2>CMS settings</h2>

<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields( 'cms-options' ); ?>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr valign="top">
          <td scope="row"><?php _e('Categories');?></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="fp_categories" class="regular-text" value="<?php echo get_option('fp_categories'); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
          <td scope="row"><?php _e('Tags');?></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="fp_tags" class="regular-text" value="<?php echo get_option('fp_tags); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>                       
    </table>

    <div id="fileBrowser" title="File browser"> </div>

    <p class="submit">
    <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>" />
    </p>

</form>
</div>
<?php }
```

Comment: Um... I would change the `administrator` rights in `add_menu_page`. I think now only admins will see the menu.

Comment: It doesn´t save the input in the two fields. When I hit "Save changes", its doesn´t really save.

Comment: That's because the inputs don't have the correct names.

Comment: t31os is right. You must change the name of the input fields. See my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Justin Tadlock's [Query Posts](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/03/15/query-posts-widget-wordpress-plugin) plugin?

Comment: Thanks a plugin just for admins, right? I´m looking for something that is easy to use for the users of my site.

Comment: What is your site's purpose? You speak of "users" and I assumed you meant WordPress authors, but it sounds like something different.

Comment: I´m speaking of regular people using the site. My site is not a blog, but more like twitter. The users should be able to customize what they see on the home page.

Comment: Have you considered BuddyPress? Users can easily customize what shows up in their streams...