# Fields in User Profile Page

Tags: profiles

I have a question and would like help from friends. I want to add two fields on the page of users registered on my blog. I added some pictures to brighten my explanation.

1. When we register a user manually, following User> Add User, I would add this field:
   [image]
2. When a user is already registered and following User> Users> (select the user and click edit), I would add this field:
   [image]

I saw several blogs / forum that show how to add input on the contact and how to create a new block, but found nothing that could be the way I like.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Add Custom Form Fields To The User Profile Page?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4028/how-to-add-custom-form-fields-to-the-user-profile-page)

Comment: Please search before asking

Comment: You read my post? You looked at the pictures? Add fields that way I know. I would like to add on down the field select Role.

Comment: You arrow cleary points _below_ the field, not at the select-option drop-down field. And I can't read that you want to add additional roles in your Q. There are plugins for that. Example: Role Scoper and various others.

Comment: Here a example: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/694/profile2demo.png/. I edited user-new.php and add this field, but I cannot edit user-new.php in production. So, exists any function to make it?

Comment: First: Never edit core files. These edits are lost on update. Second: It's exactly what I thought - a duplicate. See the the linked Q.

Comment: Are you trying to also reposition the new field? Maybe you can try this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/39295/1044

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Add Custom Form Fields To The User Profile Page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4028/how-to-add-custom-form-fields-to-the-user-profile-page)

Answer (score 1):

For a quick solution put this code in functions.php of your theme:

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'show_extra_profile_fields', 10 );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'show_extra_profile_fields', 10 );

function show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
    <input type="text" name="twitter" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'twitter', $user->ID ) ); ?>" />
<?php }
```

Or you could do it with a plugin: http://www.cozmoslabs.com/wordpress-profile-builder/

Answer (score 0):

check this link
[Add Custom Fields to User Profile](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields)