# Add description text under input field for new profile fields

Tags: custom-field, functions, profiles, input, labels

How can I modify my following code to add some description text under the input fields? I tried modifying it as you can see with the facebook url field but the text shows up under the field label and not the actual input field --

```
function modify_contact_methods($profile_fields) {
    // Add new fields
    $profile_fields['address'] = 'Address';
    $profile_fields['city'] = 'City';
    $profile_fields['state'] = 'State';
    $profile_fields['zipcode'] = 'Zip Code';
    $profile_fields['phone'] = 'Phone Number';
    $profile_fields['fax'] = 'Fax';
    $profile_fields['gplus'] = 'Google+ URL';
    $profile_fields['twitter'] = 'Twitter URL';
    $profile_fields['facebook'] = 'Facebook URL <br /><span style="clear:both;">Ex: www.facebook.com/username</span>';
    // Remove old fields
    unset($profile_fields['aim']);
    unset($profile_fields['yim']);
    unset($profile_fields['jabber']);

    return $profile_fields;
}
add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'modify_contact_methods');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on information gathered [HERE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39285/user-profile-add-custom-fields) and [HERE](http://wpengineer.com/2173/custom-fields-wordpress-user-profile/); I was able to put something together.

First... abandon your first approach.  It will add a field value, yes.  But it will not allow you to add a descriptive field.

Instead, we need to create an entire new `table` tag in the structure that gets populated from WordPress.  To do so, let's use this function:

```
function my_custom_user_profile_fields( $user ) {
    ?>
    <table id="facebook_user_field_table" class="form-table">
        <tr id="facebook_user_field_row">
            <th>
                <label for="facebook_field"><?php _e('Facebook URL', 'your_textdomain'); ?></label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="facebook_field" id="facebook_field" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'facebook_field', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
                <span class="description"><?php _e('Please enter your Facebook profile url.', 'your_textdomain'); ?></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php 
}
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'my_custom_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_custom_user_profile_fields' );
```

That will define our new `tr` element, and populate it with the necessary structure.  You may change the field label and description to suit your needs.

NOTE: This will only create our new `tr` element, and place it at the bottom of the "About Yourself" section.  In order to 'place' the new `tr` element where we want (ie the "Contact Info"), we have to use a bit of jQuery:

```
function my_facebook_field_placement_js() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( $screen->id != "profile" && $screen->id != "user-edit" ) 
    return;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            field = $('#facebook_user_field_row').remove();
            parent = $('#url').closest('tr');
            field.insertBefore(parent);
        });
    </script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'my_facebook_field_placement_js' );
```

This code will take our new `tr` element, and add it BEFORE the "WEBSITE" field that is generated by WordPress.

NOTE: See how we are hooking to `admin_head` here?  We want to make sure this doesn't run on every admin page. So, the first part of this code block will check the current page, and only run the code if we are on the profile page.

Now... that's great.  Placement is Perfect!!  But wait... now our data is not saving when we update the fields.  Fret not!!  We have another hook for that:

```
function my_save_custom_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return FALSE;

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'facebook_field', $_POST['facebook_field'] );
}
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'my_save_custom_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'my_save_custom_user_profile_fields' );
```

This will update the field, and store it in the user meta table.  Then, whenever you need to access this value from your template; just use the `get_user_meta` function.

Comment: Another good one, +1. I'd do a micro-optimization: `if( !in_array( get_current_screen()->id, array('profile','user-edit') ) ) return;`

Comment: Wow! - "micro-whatchamacallit".. awesome. I've always declared *get_current_screen()* as a variable first. Very cool!!  Thank you.

Comment: Well, that's micro-micro optimization, but if we're calling the function only once, then goodbye var... I only arrived at this recently, nice you liked :)