# Let user select their own category

Tags: categories, taxonomy, user-meta

I would like to let category editor appear to any user and user can edit their preferred category(ies).

**For example:**
the category is about kind of job or profession and there are 10 categories(professions).
When user login, they can edit profile and they can choose their profession as well.
I can imagine that creating a custom taxonomy and let it appear in every user's menu.
But how can I store individual user's selection? Is it possible to display a list in profile and let the user to check and save?

How it should be implemented? Any idea is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why I am being down-voted? If I know what's wrong, I can improve in the future. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`User taxonomies` can help you achieve this, I'm working on something similar.
You can install the plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-taxonomies/, and register a custom taxonomy , although in my case the plugin has some limitations, may be it helps you.

```
register_taxonomy('profession', 'user', array(
'public'      =>true,
'labels'      =>array(
    'name'                        =>'Professions',
    'singular_name'               =>'Profession',
    'menu_name'                   =>'Professions',
    'search_items'                =>'Search Professions',
    'popular_items'               =>'Popular Professions',
    'all_items'                   =>'All Professions',
    'edit_item'                   =>'Edit Profession',
    'update_item'             =>'Update Profession',
    'add_new_item'                =>'Add New Profession',
    'new_item_name'               =>'New Profession Name',
    'separate_items_with_commas'=>'Separate professions with commas',
    'add_or_remove_items'     =>'Add or remove professions',
    'choose_from_most_used'       =>'Choose from the most popular professions',
),
'rewrite'     =>array(
    'with_front'              =>true,
    'slug'                        =>'author/profession',
),
'capabilities'    => array(
    'manage_terms'                =>'edit_users',
    'edit_terms'              =>'edit_users',
    'delete_terms'                =>'edit_users',
    'assign_terms'                =>'read',
),
));
```

**Update**

I've compiled a similar plugin [User Tags](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-tags) which might help you.

Comment: Sorry for late, for my project has changed the flow design. So I left the test behind. I have tried. Your concept and suggested plugins solve the problem. And I just found out another plugin that is just complement. [user-tags](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-tags/) use tag system. With these plugins as reference, in the future, anyone can use or create their own solutions. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, actually I wrote the plugin User Tags => http://codechutney.com/user-tags-wordpress/ as the previous plugin was limited and wasn't updated anymore. Hope it could be of help to you, in case you require some help with the plugin you can raise a support request too.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways you could do this. Essentially, I'd split the process into 3 parts.

  1. Decide the professions you'll offer (or let users create their own), and display to    the user.

          2. Save the profession the user chooses, and associate with that user's ID.         

          3. Decide how and where you display the information.

There are a few options on how to do this. Here are a couple:
[This](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/39295/43615) answer here on SE has a good explanation.
If you're looking for more flexibility and future customisation, I'd recommend a plugin I've used on a few sites, and I really like: [CMB](https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress) is really well documented too.

Comment: Thanks for your information. Your suggestion did inpsire and can be used to solve other problem too. I originally want to upvote you but I don't have enough reputation.