# Add additional Fields for users and get value

Tags: user-meta

I have register form where all users is subscribers in system, few fields is store in meta table in database, how i can get this user meta key in additionals field for each users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meta table? (wp_usermeta or wp_postmeta)?

You can get any meta of user by [get_user_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta)

Comment: wp_usermeta and i need display this value in field in user section, and if possible need update this user meta in profile page

Comment: Lerry, see this question [#39285](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39285/user-profile-add-custom-fields)