# Let Users Choose Post Categories

Tags: php, categories, user-meta, homepage

EDIT:

Using a 3rd party free theme that is called IsleMag.

http://themeisle.com/themes/islemag/

I am wanting to develop it in order to allow users to customise it to see football news that **they** want to see.

In terms of screenshots, I'm starting the news block from scratch... I'm printing the screenshot below as evidence that I've copied the code you requested into my functions.php file...

[[image: functions.php file]]

I am confused though where to put this line of code: "$data = get_the_author_meta( 'user_categories', $user->ID );"

**Please help! :) **

---

I've tried looking up this solution but haven't got anywhere, even [with this guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqSxS.png) (can't seem to locate what to put on the index.php file)...

Its for a football news site that I've designed and am running and looking to allow users (football fans) to customise their own homepage to show news articles that are specifically of their chosen post category(ies) (which are teams) - to display news articles (posts) from that category(ies) only.

The web addy is: www.entirelyfootball.co.uk  -- please help ASAP!! :)

**What I'm basically trying to do is:**

1) Add fields in the form of radio (check) boxes in "Your Profile" (individual user profiles) with options like: (1) West Ham United  (2) Norwich City  3) Arsenal FC - and allow more than one to be ticked/selected - all of these will be post categories

2) Depending on which fields/options the user has checked (ticked) in their profile, I want to grab this/these category's ID and create a block of news articles on my index.php file that will display the post title, post thumbnail post excerpt (limited to a certain number of characters - say 25) and a link to the individual post... But this must be grabbed by that user's ID and must remember to load the same correct layout the next time the user logs back in.

3) If no fields have been selected, I need an opening if and else(?) statement so that I can fill a default homepage block of news articles that are grabbed from all categories - where none has been set/ticked - so the same layout: post title, post thumbnail, post excerpt (limited to a certain number of characters - say 25) and a link to the individual post.

> > Can this be done with a PHP if and else statement????

--

It is...

...similar to this (couldn't find the solution in the form of code to put in my index.php file) (removed due to not allowing me to post more than 2 links)

Answer (score 0):

First, you will have to add the categories to user profiles. This question [has been addressed before](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28407/adding-custom-user-profile-data-based-upon-categories). That will give you the possibility to retrieve an array $data with the category ID' a user is interested in.

Now, you will need to turn that array into a list of posts. Depending on where you want to show it, this goes in `index.php` or `sidebar.php` or maybe even `footer.php`. You could also make into a widget. At the location where you eventually need your html you write:

```
$data = get_the_author_meta( 'user_categories', $user->ID );
if (empty($data)) $data = array (1, 2, 3, 4); // default categories to show
```

Next you need to [define a query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) which restricts the returned posts to those belonging to a specific category. It wil look something like this:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'cat' => $data ) );
```

Now `$query` holds an array of max 3 posts in categories with the desired ID's. You can use a `foreach` loop to go through them in the usual way.

Comment: Hi @cjbj - How do I include the $query and the $data tags?? Can you write it as an example in what situation you'd write it as?

Comment: @MorganMcLellan That's impossible to tell without more context. Are you developing your own theme or are you using a third party one? In case of the latter, do you have a child theme? Are there hooks in the theme you could use?

Comment: do you have an email address or another form of contact as will be able to discuss with screenshots maybe via Facebook or Twitter (way more quicker and able to copy and paste to send screenshots to you)?? Thanks, Morgan

Comment: Please can you email me: morgan@entirelyfootball.co.uk - I'll be able to reply within about 2 minutes so much much quicker

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify it (with images). WPSE is a resource for WordPress developers, not a free helpdesk. So any solution must take place on the site, for others to learn from.

Comment: **Done - added above**

Comment: please let me know & advise as intrigued as to the solution to this - could be very interesting to others & especially those developing potential sites that will use this cool feature

Comment: First, you will need to make a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), so your adaptations are separated from the original theme. The new block of code goes in the `functions.php` of your child theme. Then you need to identify the place in other template files where you want the user dependent info to appear. The other code goes there. If you have no idea how to do this, you probably need professional assistance.

Comment: Please can I have some help? I've never created a child theme but can usually get my head around it if someone pin-points exactly what to do...

Comment: There are plenty of online tutorials on creating child themes. WPSE is meant to help you with very specific problems, not with mastering the basics of WordPress.

Comment: Ok, just creating the child theme now. This particular bit seems very simple.

Comment: Come up with the following error message: "Template is missing. Standalone themes need to have a index.php template file. Child themes need to have a Template header in the style.css stylesheet."

Comment: ignore the Child Theme bit as I now have my theme backed up. I've tried setting it up but it comes up with that error message... Please can we move onto proceeding after putting that code into the functions.php file??

Comment: @MorganMcLellan Morgan, the user helped you, it will be appropriate, if you made an upvote to him on his answers.