# Customize field names in backend profile edit page through function.php

Tags: php, functions, profiles, customization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How To Add Custom Form Fields To The User Profile Page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4028/how-to-add-custom-form-fields-to-the-user-profile-page)

I want to change a the names of some of the fields in the edit profile page in the backend. For instance, instead of it saying "Twitter", I want it to display "Enter Twitter ID".

I am aware that I can do this by editing the core WP files, but to avoid redoing the same process, how can I do this through the function.php file? What code can I enter that would make this possible?

Comment: Please [search](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/4028/251) before asking questions.  This has been answered multiple times.

Comment: Respectfully, I believe that you read my question incorrectly. I was asking for ways to change the existing form fields, not add new ones.

Comment: And there are answers on the linked questions that show you how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to look at is hooking into the `user_contactmethods` filter.

Perhaps something along these lines:

```
function test_new_contact(){
  $user_contactmethods = array(
      'aim' => __('AIM'),
      'yim' => __('Yahoo IM'),
      'jabber' => __('Jabber / Google Talk'),
      'twitter' => __( 'Enter Twitter ID' ),
  );
  return $user_contactmethods;
}
add_filter( 'user_contactmethods', 'test_new_contact' );
```

Note the "core" user contact methods should be included in your filter function, unless of course you want to remove them ... then simply do not include them at all.