# Removing user fields

Tags: wp-admin, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How To Add Custom Form Fields To The User Profile Page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4028/how-to-add-custom-form-fields-to-the-user-profile-page)

I'm current removing some user fields with the following code in the functions.php file:

```
function adjust_contact_methods( $contactmethods ) {
  unset($contactmethods['aim']);
  unset($contactmethods['jabber']);
  unset($contactmethods['yim']);
  unset($contactmethods['twitter']);
  return $contactmethods;
}
add_filter('user_contactmethods','adjust_contact_methods',10,1);
```

I'd like to additionally remove the website and Google+ fields, but I can't find the correct keyword. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
unset($contactmethods['googleplus']);
```

Is what I needed to add to my above code.

Comment: Because it wouldn't let me yet. Had to wait.

Comment: Gotcha. Forget how stringent SE is sometimes. :)

Comment: Remind me in 4 hours. :-)

Comment: WordPress SEO plugin is adding a few additional contact methods (googleplus, twitter and facebook). In order to unset googleplus, you'd need to add the filter with a higher number in the priority parameter. For instance `add_filter( 'user_contactmethods', 'magn_unset_contactmethods', 1000 );`

Answer (score 1):

The following function is from WordPress 3.4.1 default installation source file 'user.php' starting at line 1481.

```
/**
 * Set up the default contact methods
 *
 * @access private
 * @since
 *
 * @param object $user User data object (optional)
 * @return array $user_contactmethods Array of contact methods and their labels.
 */
function _wp_get_user_contactmethods( $user = null ) {
    $user_contactmethods = array(
        'aim' => __('AIM'),
        'yim' => __('Yahoo IM'),
        'jabber' => __('Jabber / Google Talk')
    );
    return apply_filters( 'user_contactmethods', $user_contactmethods, $user );
}
```

Additional fields might have been set vi addfilter hooks.

```
add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'my_user_contactmethods');  

function my_user_contactmethods($user_contactmethods){  

  $user_contactmethods['twitter'] = 'Twitter Username';  
  $user_contactmethods['facebook'] = 'Facebook Username';  

  return $user_contactmethods;  
}
```

`$user_contactmethods` is an array.

Try the following code to output the array in one of your pages.

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($user_contactmethods);
echo "</pre>";
```

You will see an array. figure out the key related to Google Plus and unset it.

```
unset($contactmethods['YOUR_GOOGLE_PLUS_KEY']);
```