# How to give different user access to different people?

Tags: plugins, customization, users, user-roles, user-access

I have a video tutorial website where I have to provide videos. For that purpose I have to give different user access to those who login to particular courses.

So can you please help me what is the functionality for user access manager?

Comment: You can give them different Roles on your site. See [Roles and Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

1. The most obvious approach to this would be to first [create a
   special user role](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role) for your students.
2. Then for users with this role you can [expand the profile with extra
   fields](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4028/how-to-add-custom-form-fields-to-the-user-profile-page). Here you can store for every user which courses they
   follow.
3. Next you define a [custom post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) that allows you to store the
   video labelled with the courses for which it is meant.
4. Finally, in your templates, you check if the content of user fields
   matches the labels of the video, to make sure users only see the
   videos they should get.