# How to do action form from functions.php?

Tags: uploads, profiles

For a specific development, I had to add a upload form to change the profile photo inside the admin user page.

**functions.php**

```
function add_link_avatar( $description, $profileuser ){
    $description .= '<form action="#">';
    $description .= '<input type="file" name="fileupload" value="fileupload" id="fileupload" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png">';
    $description .= '<input type="submit" value="submit" class="button">';
    $description .= '</form>';
    echo $description;
}
add_filter( 'user_profile_picture_description' , 'add_link_avatar' , 1 , 2 );
```

How can I get the $_POST in `functions.php` ?

What value it needs for the `action` attribute ?

Comment: The action is used to determine where the form will be submitted. You can use `$_FILES['fileupload']` in your functions.php to get the files. Also you should add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form.

Comment: Thank you ! To get $_FILES, how can bind the form with a specific function inside functions.php ?

Comment: You're welcome. This will be saved when the user saves their profiles, so you can bind your function to the `edit_user_profile_update` action hook. [Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/edit_user_profile_update) is an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Add Custom Form Fields To The User Profile Page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4028/how-to-add-custom-form-fields-to-the-user-profile-page)